# How to write a function that returns an array of indices of values in array x in array y?

Tags: f#

I am trying to write an efficient algorithm that will effectively let me merge data sets (like a sql join).  I think I need to use Array.tryFindIndex, but the syntax has me lost.

Based on the data below, I am calling arrX my "host" array, and want to return an int array that has its length, and tells me the positions of each of its elements in arrY (returning -1 if its not in there). (Once I know these indices I can then use them on arrays of data that of length arrY.length)

```
let arrX= [|"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F"|]
let arrY = [|"E";"A";"C"|];


let desiredIndices = [|1; -1; 2; -1; 0; -1|]
```

It looks like I need to use an option type somehow, and I think a mapi2 in there as well.
Does anyone know how to get this done?  (I think it could be a very useful code snippet for people who are merging data sets from different sources)

Thanks!

```
//This code does not compile, can't figure out what to do here
let d = Array.tryFindIndex (fun x y -> x = y) arrX
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tryFindIndex` function searches for a single element in the array specified as the second argument. The lambda function gets only a single parameter and it should return `true` if the parameter is the element you are looking for. The type signature of the `tryFindIndex` function shows this:

```
('a -> bool) -> 'a [] -> int option
```

(In your example, you're giving it a function that takes two parameters of type `'a -> 'a -> bool`, which is incompatible with the expected type). The `tryFindIndex` function returns an option type, which means that it gives you `None` if no element matches the predicate, otherwise it gives you `Some(idx)` containing the index of the found element.

To get the desired array of indices, you need to run `tryFindIndex` for every element of the input array (`arrX`). This can be done using the `Array.map` function. If you want to get -1 if the element wasn't found, you can use pattern matching to convert `None` to -1 and `Some(idx)` to `idx`:

```
let desired = 
  arrX |> Array.map (fun x ->
    let res = Array.tryFindIndex (fun y -> x = y) arrY 
    match res with 
    | None -> -1 
    | Some idx -> idx)
```

The same thing can be written using sequence expression (instead of `map`), which may be more readable:

```
let desired = 
  [| for x in arrX do 
       let res = Array.tryFindIndex (fun y -> x = y) arrY 
       match res with 
       | None -> yield -1 
       | Some idx -> yield idx |]
```

Anyway, if you need to implement a join-like operation, you can do it more simply using sequence expressions. In the following example, I also added some values (in addition to the string keys), so that you can better see how it works:

```
let arrX= [|"A",1; "B",2; "C",3; "D",4; "E",5; "F",6|] 
let arrY = [|"E",10; "A",20; "C",30|]

[| for x, i in arrX do 
    for y, j in arrY do
      if x = y then 
        yield x, i, j |]

// Result:   [|("A", 1, 20); ("C", 3, 30); ("E", 5, 10)|]
```

The sequence expression simply loops over all `arrX` elements and for each of them, it loops over all `arrY` element. Then it tests whether the keys are the same and if they are, it produces a single element. This isn't particularly efficient, but in most of the cases, it should work fine.

Comment: Glad I could help :-). I also added a note about implementing join-like operations using sequence expressions.

Comment: this is quite helpful - thanks.  Incidentally I just read your book and am now trying to write code without referring to it (too much).

Comment: This isn't efficient O(n * m).  You may want to consider something different if you are using large data sets.

Comment: @gradbot: Yes - both of the versions are O(n*m) and the second one is a bit less efficent (assuming that `arrY` doesn't contain duplicates). More sophisticated implementation could be implemented for example using hasing and `Dictionary<TKey, TValues>`.

Answer (score 3):

Write a custom function that returns -1 if nothing is found, or returns the index if it's found.  Next, use Array.map to map a new array using this function:

```
let arrX= [|"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F"|]
let arrY = [|"E";"A";"C"|];

let indexOrNegativeOne x =
    match Array.tryFindIndex (fun y -> y = x) arrY with
    | Some(y) -> y
    | None -> -1

let desired = arrX |> Array.map indexOrNegativeOne
printfn "%A" desired
```